# Why is DIV outside of containing DIV?

Tags: html, css

What is causing this webpage to be so screwed up: http://scratchpad.io/tame-cork-2164?

The footer should be across the bottom and the sidebar section on the right. The side is outside of the main div for some reason.

```html
<div style="border:1px solid black">
  <header>
    <h2>Web Page</h2>
  </header>
  <nav>page 1 page 2 page 3</nav>
  <div style="float:left;width:50%;border:1px solid black">
    <section>
      section 1
    </section>
    <article>Any article content goes here.</article>
    <section>
      <p>section 2</p>
      <p>section 2</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div style="float:right;width:50%;border:1px solid black">
    <aside><a href="/">a sidebar</a></aside>
  </div>
</div>
<footer style="width:100%">Copyright 2018</footer>
```

Comment: the first dupe deal with float element and the second one with border combined with width and no need width:100% for the footer it's by default

Comment: clear the floats in the footer, or use flexbox instead of floats.

Comment: @FunkDoc: There aren't any floats in the footer. But why doesn't the footer stretch across the bottom?

Comment: @TemaniAfif: I removed the 100% but not sure what you mean on the other stuff.

Comment: You 'll need to do some research on how floats work https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp

Comment: I meant you have 2 issues an each one is explained in each duplicate